Algorithms to Find Convex Combination Coefficients for a Point within a Convex Polytope Without Explicit Representation
Set Up: Let $P$ be a finite convex polytope. Assume that we do not have a representation for $P$ (like a V-, H- or Z-representation of $P$), all we have is an algorithm which can find a point of $P$ which maximises any linear functional over $P$. (I detail a scenario in which this could be the case below). We also assume, that given some set $A$, like an affine space, we could determine the point of $P \cap A$ which maximises some linear functional.
Question: What algorithms can be used to find the coefficients of a convex combination of vertices of $P$ equal to some $x \in P$?
Attempt: So far we have tried to consider adaptations of the standard algorithm for finding a suitable convex combination: Let $u_0 = x$ and $v_0$ be some vertex of $P$. Now, for $i \geq 1$, let $u_i$ be the point such that $[u_{i}, v_{i-1}] = P \cap \mathrm{aff}\{u_{i-1}, v_{i-1}\}$, and $v_i$ be a vertex of the proper face containing $u_{i}$. For $i \geq 0$, let $\lambda_i$ be the real number such that $u_{i} = \lambda_iv_{i} + (1-\lambda_i)u_{i+1}$. We have that $u_{d+1}$ must be a vertex of $P$, where $d$ is the dimension of $P$ and $$x = \lambda_0v_{0} + (1-\lambda_0)(\lambda_1v_{1} + (1-\lambda_1)(\cdots(\lambda_{d}v_{d} + (1-\lambda_d)u_{d+1})\cdots)).$$ In our set up, it is possible to obtain a vertex of $P$ (with probability $1$) and obtain the $u_1$. Can we construct a linear functional at each step which is maximised over $P$ by $v_i$? Is there an alternative approach which works?
Example Scenario (this can be safely skipped).
In multi-objective reinforcement learning  with a finite state and action space, the set of value functions for a fixed state and all possible policies is a finite convex polytope. This polytope $P$ has an unknown representation, but points within it can be determined by constructing suitable policies. Namely, we can run reinforcement learning algorithms to learn a policy which maximises the dot product between the value it returns and a given direction. Thus we can find the vertices of $P$ (or at least approximate them).

Perhaps the Frank Wolfe algorithm to find the nearest point in $P$ to $x$?

Without loss of generality, you may assume $x = 0$ (you can just translate both $x$ and your polytope by $-x$). Since you can find the maximizer of a functional on $P$, you can always compute the (maximizer of the) support function in a given direction $d$, which is given as
$$\rho(d) = \max_{y\in P} d^\top x.$$
Sometimes, the maximizer is called the support vector, and I will denote it as $\nu(d)$ here. Note that by the Bauer maximum principle, $\nu(d)$ can always be chosen to be a vertex of $P$.
Intuitively, if $d$ is a unit vector, $\rho(d)$ tells you the distance between the origin and the boundary of a halfspace orthogonal to $d$ that contains your polytope. In a way, $\nu(d)$ can give you the furthest vertex in direction $d$.
Now, consider the following algorithm:
Step 1. Start with a random vector $d$ (you could also just take $d = e_1$ for instance), and compute the vertices $v_0 = \nu(d)$ and $v_1 = \nu(-d)$.
Step 2. If $0$ is a convex combination of the vertices you have found so far, you are done. Otherwise, go to Step 3.
Step 3. Compute the center over all your current vertices, i.e., $d = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^N v_i$.
Step 4. Compute the next vertex $v_{N+1} = \nu(-d)$, and go to Step 2.
To prove this algorithm works, it suffices to show that after Step 4, the new vertex $v_{N+1}$ that you find can not be part of the vertices you have found before (otherwise you might get stuck in an infinite loop).
Proving this can get a bit technical (you need the hyperplane separation theorem), but here's a sketch: let $P'$ be the polytope with vertices $v_0,...,v_N$. Clearly, $d \in P'$, but $0 \not\in P'$ so you can find a hyperplane separating $P'$ from the origin; roughly speaking, you can then orient the space such that $P'$ (and thus $d$) is on the 'left' of this hyperplane, while the origin is on the 'right'. Consequently, if you search for a vertex in direction $-d$, you will end up with a vertex on the 'right' side of the hyperplane, which can thus not be one of the vertices you have found so far.
I can't promise that this algorithm is the fastest one, but it is deterministic and its worst-case runtime scales with the number of vertices of $P$; as a matter of fact, I suspect it might only need $\mathcal{O}(n)$ iterations, since you only need $n+1$ vertices for a convex combination, where $n$ is the dimension of the ambient space. However, this proof might be more complicated...
